# What airs on TV in Japan during the break between the fall and winter anime season?

Tags: anime-production

With little to no new anime airing in the next week or so, with fall season now being over and winter season starting in January, I for the life of me, cannot figure out what airs on TV in Japan to take the place of anime which would usually air. Wouldn't there be a lot of empty time slots? They can't fill them up with Christmas specials right? Christmas isn't even that big in Japan from what I know.

Comment: New Years.  They celebrate New Years.

Comment: Date a Japanese girl and tell her that! lol (And then get ready to load up the Brinks trucks)